# How $|S(x_n, \xi_n) - S(x'_n, \xi'_n)|$ being arbitrary small implies existence of Stieltjes-Riemann Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, proof-explanation, stieltjes-integral

I am studying *Multiplicative number theory I: Classical theory by Hugh L. Montgomery, Robert C. Vaughan* ([E-book](https://library.lol/main/207BE3298F0ABEE321DF6BA0F0887561)). In Appendix A, Theorem A.1. states that $I = \int f dg$ exists if $f$ is continuous and $g$ is of bounded variation. Let $a=x_0 \le x_1 \le \dots \le x_N=b$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, and $S(x_n, \xi_n) = \sum_1^N f(\xi_n) (g(x_n)-g(x_{n-1}))$. The proof claims that for existence of $I$ it is sufficient to prove that for every $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ such that $|I - S(x_n, \xi_n)|<\epsilon$. It is clear up to this point. Then it is claimed that it is sufficient to prove that $|S(x_n, \xi_n) - S(x'_n, \xi'_n)|<2 \epsilon \text{Var(g)}$ for two arbitrary partitions $x_n$ and $x'_n$. I could follow all steps of the proof and I can see that $|S(x_n, \xi_n) - S(x'_n, \xi'_n)|<2 \epsilon \text{Var(g)}$ is true. But why $|S(x_n, \xi_n) - S(x'_n, \xi'_n)|<2 \epsilon \text{Var(g)}$ being true implies $|I - S(x_n, \xi_n)|<\epsilon$ to be true **??**

Comment: If my question is not good enough and that's the reason for not receiving any answer, please let me know your suggestions to improve my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me consider fixed $g$, so "Cauchy like" property for inequality $(A.2)$ can be formulated as following:

$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists\delta >0,$ such that for $\forall$  partitions $x'_n,x''_n$ with mesh $< \delta$, holds
$$|S(x'_n, \xi_n)-S(x''_n, \xi'_n)|<\varepsilon \quad(A.2)$$
where $\xi_n, \xi'_n$ are any from corresponding intervals.

Now, let's consider $\varepsilon_n=\frac{1}{n}, n\in \mathbb{N}$ and choose for any $n$ choose $\delta_n$, for which holds $(A.2)$. We are able consider $\delta_n$ monotone decreasing. Also, for any $n$ we can choose partition $x_n$ with mesh $\lambda_{x_n}<\delta_n$ and take $\xi_n$ from this partition intervals. Let's denote  Riemann–Stieltjes sum for obtained values by  $T_n$. For exactness we can write $\lambda_{x_n}$ as $\lambda_{T_n}$.

For given any $\forall \varepsilon>0$ we can find $N$ for which $\varepsilon_N < \varepsilon$. For any $k,m>N$ we have $\lambda_{T_m }<\delta_m<\delta_N$ and $\lambda_{T_k }<\delta_k<\delta_N$, so from $(A.2)$ holds
$$|T_k - T_m|< \varepsilon$$
This gives, that $T_n$ converged and we can show, that its limit $T$ will be integral.

For this for $\forall \varepsilon>0$ we find $n$, such that $\varepsilon_n < \varepsilon$. For any $p>n$ we have $\lambda_{T_p }<\delta_p\leqslant \delta_n$, so for any partition $\{x\}$ with mesh $<\delta_n$ and  corresponding any collection of $\xi$ we will have
$$|T_p-S(\{x\},\xi)|< \varepsilon_n$$
Taking limit $p\to\infty$ in last inequality gives
$$|T-S(\{x\},\xi)|\leqslant \varepsilon_n < \varepsilon$$
which mean, that $T$ is integral

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read it thoroughly and I have an issue for understanding it ...

Comment: ... First we choose some partition and derive (say) $S_1$. We know that if there is a second partition such that mesh of both partitions are less $\delta_n$ then $|S_2-S_1|<1/n$. By a theorem (outside the book), I also know that if $\delta_m \to 0$ then $S_m \to \int$ for a sequence of partitions numbered by index $m$. The critical point to answer my question in OP is the claim that if we make $\epsilon_n := 1/n$ smaller then the corresponding $\delta_n$ will be smaller AND tends to $0$ when $\epsilon_n \to 0$. How do you prove this?

Comment: I find it difficult to understand which ones $\varepsilon_n, \delta_n$ you are using in the question in comment above. Those that I have for $T_n$? If so, can you formulate your question in the context of my proof? In my text $\delta_n$ exists  for $\varepsilon_n$ to proof Cauchy property for $T_n$. Here there is not needed for $\delta_n$ tends to zero as we have sentences for any partitions with mesh less then $\delta_n$ - for inequalities I am using only monotone decreasing of $\delta_n$.

Comment: OK, in your answer you said "We are able consider δ_n
 monotone decreasing." How do you guarantee existence of "monotone decreasing"?

Comment: If existed $\delta_{n+1}$ is more, then $\delta_n$, then let's choose as $\delta_{n+1}$  any number between $0$ and $\delta_n$.

Comment: Are you from Georgia? I lived in Tblisi in 2012-2013. Very nice memories especially the kindest people :)

Comment: These were wonderful years - there was no war, no viruses and kindest people..